# multi line value in MsgBox

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vb6, vba

how can I retreive the values stored in vSum variable
multi line in one msgbox 
insted of retrive in multi msgbox one after one

```
Dim rSEL, rSUM, rDes As DAO.Recordset
Dim vItem_id, vQnty, vSum As Integer
Dim vDes As String
If Not IsNull(itemId) And Not IsNull(qnty_in) Then
    If qnty_in <= 0 Or qnty_in > balance Or IsNull(balance) Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Set rSEL = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT item_id,item_qnty 
               FROM basketQnty_tbl WHERE basket_id=" & basketId)
    'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rSEL.EOF And rSEL.BOF) Then
    rSEL.MoveFirst
    Do Until rSEL.EOF
        'Save itemId into a variable
        vItem_id = rSEL!item_id
        vQnty = (rSEL!item_qnty) * qnty_in
        Set rSUM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT sum(qnty_in*qnty_type) 
                   as QN FROM sales_tbl WHERE itemid=" & vItem_id)
        Set rDes = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT itemDesc 
                   FROM items_main WHERE itemId=" & vItem_id)
        vSum = rSUM!QN
        vDes = rDes!itemDesc
        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        If vQnty > vSum Then
            MsgBox "you have only (" & vSum & " ) of Item (" & vDes & " ) in the stock"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    rSEL.MoveNext
    Loop
    End If
   rSEL.Close
End If
```

how can I solve it ?!

Answer (score 2):

Make an array variable to hold all of the message strings. Make it bigger than you'll need, then Redim Preserve to reduce it to the proper size once you know how many messages you have.  Finally, use Join to show all the messages in one MsgBox. Here's an example.

```
Dim rSEL, rSUM, rDes As DAO.Recordset
Dim vItem_id, vQnty, vSum As Integer
Dim vDes As String
Dim aMsg() As String
Dim lCnt As Long

If Not IsNull(itemId) And Not IsNull(qnty_in) Then

    If qnty_in <= 0 Or qnty_in > balance Or IsNull(balance) Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

    Set rSEL = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT item_id,item_qnty FROM basketQnty_tbl WHERE basket_id=" & basketId)
    'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rSEL.EOF And rSEL.BOF) Then
        rSEL.MoveFirst

        ReDim aMsg(1 To rSEL.RecordCount * 10) 'make it bigger than you'll need

        Do Until rSEL.EOF
            'Save itemId into a variable
            vItem_id = rSEL!item_id
            vQnty = (rSEL!item_qnty) * qnty_in
            Set rSUM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT sum(qnty_in*qnty_type) as QN FROM sales_tbl WHERE itemid=" & vItem_id)
            Set rDes = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT itemDesc FROM items_main WHERE itemId=" & vItem_id)
            vSum = rSUM!QN
            vDes = rDes!itemDesc
            'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
            If vQnty > vSum Then
                lCnt = lCnt + 1
                aMsg(lCnt) = "you have only (" & vSum & " ) of Item (" & vDes & " ) in the stock"
            End If
           rSEL.MoveNext
        Loop
        If lCnt >= 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve aMsg(1 To lCnt)
            MsgBox Join(aMsg, vbNewLine)
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
   rSEL.Close

End If
```

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Dick 
that exactuly what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` in order to construct the resulting message. This is more efficient than concatenating strings, because `StringBuilder` has an efficient memory management, i.e. it does not assign new memory after each string operation; instead it works with an internal buffer.

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder

sb = New StringBuilder()

...
Do Until rSEL.EOF
    ....
    sb.Append("you have only (") _
      .Append(vSum) _
      .Append(" ) of Item (") _
      .Append(vDes) _
      .AppendLine(" ) in the stock")
    rSEL.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox sb.ToString()
```

---

Alternatively, you could combine the string builder with `String.Format`

```
...
Do Until rSEL.EOF
    ....
    sb.AppendLine( _
        String.Format("you have only ({0} ) of Item ({1} ) in the stock", vSum, vDes) _
    )
    rSEL.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox sb.ToString()
```

This is much easier to read.

Or even easier:

```
    ...
    sb.AppendFormat("you have only ({0} ) of Item ({1} ) in the stock", vSum, vDes) _
      .AppendLine()
    ...
```

Comment: StringBuilder is not include

Comment: Add a `Using System.Text`

Comment: how please describe me ?!

Comment: Sorry it's "Imports" in VB (using is C#). At the top of the code include a line `Imports System.Text` or use the smart tag that appears at `StringBuilder`. See [VB.NET StringBuilder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-vbnet)

Comment: This answer is all VB.net. Question is VBA.